# How to copy eBooks into TotalReader on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, file-sharing, ebook

I have an ebook reader app installed, TotalReader.  I downloaded an ebook and want to add it to it.

- When I open "Files" app I can select "on my ipad" and then I see 2 folders: Chrome (which has downloaded files, including the one that I want) and Keynote.
- When I go into File Manager in the TotalReader, I see Photo Album and Documents.

Is there a way to copy files from one app to another on iPad w/o going via Dropbox or something else like that?

Comment: This can only be done if the app developers coded their applications to accept this.  Not all apps have 'folders' or will accept files from outside their app (due to sandboxing rules).  If you're specifically concerned about TotalReader, you should contact the developer and ask how this can be done.

Comment: According to the App Store entry, support can be contacted via support@develsoftware.com. The most recent update of the app (any app of that developer, actually) happened three years ago though...

Answer (score -1):

Imazing program on your PC or mac can help with that. You can copy books, organise folders inside TotalReader app folder with help of it.Very useful.